# Show temperature without labels/text with "sensors" on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, sensors, lm-sensors

i want to show my gpu temperature from a terminal command using my console on ubuntu 18.04.

I installed `sensors-lm` and finished the configuration.

When i type `sensors -A radeon-pci-0100` in a terminal it shows me:

```
radeon-pci-0100
temp1:        +36.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

What i want is just the `36.0°C` chars of this output, or better just `36°C`.

How can i get this?

Thanks for help

Comment: Perhaps, it would be easier to parse in the long run if you used `-u` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-`, `+` and `°` as field separator. If row contains `temp1:` then print second column as integer and append `°C`:

```
awk -F '[-+°]' '/temp1:/ {printf("%d°C\n",$2)}' file
```

Output:

```
36°C
```

Comment: Thank you <3 so the solution for me is: `sensors -A radeon-pci-0100 | awk -F '[-+°]' '/temp1:/ {printf("%d°C\n",$2)}'`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sensors -A radeon-pci-0100 | grep temp1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '(' -f 1
```

if you want to remove the `+` sign and leading spaces:

```
sensors -A radeon-pci-0100 | grep temp1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '(' -f 1 | tr -d '+' | tr -s ' '
```

Comment: `sensors -A radeon-pci-0100 | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '(' -f 1` shows me an empty row :(